# How to execute Stored Procedure asynchronously in Java?

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a process wherein a user uploads an excel file. The contents of the excel file are stored into a SQL Server table. After the insert completes, I have a validation stored procedure that executes which validates the data uploaded. However, for files with say more than 1.5k rows of data, the validation stored procedure runs longer and on the frontend the process times out.

The function is as follows :

```
public void storeData(Sheet sheet) {
        
    int rowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();

    String rowCount;   
    Connection conn = null;
    int batchSize = 1000;
    
    try {
        conn = SqlDBConnect.getConnection("DATADB");
        
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        s.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM [dbo].[TableA]");
        
        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableA] ([ID],[NAME1],[NAME2],[COUNTRY],[Category1],[Category2],[Category3],[LEVEL]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        pstmt.setQueryTimeout(3600);
        
        for(int i = 8; i <= rowNum; i++) 
        {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
            for(int j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
            {  
                Cell cell = row.getCell(j,Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                int columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();
    
                switch (columnIndex) {
                    case 0:
                        String Id = null;
                        Object obj = getCellValue(cell);
                        if(obj.getClass().toString().contains("java.lang.Double"))
                        {
                            Id = String.valueOf((double)obj);
                            Id = Id.substring(0,Id.length() - 2);
                        }
                        else {
                            Id = obj.toString();
                        }
                        pstmt.setString(1, Id);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        pstmt.setString(2, getCellValue(cell).toString());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pstmt.setString(3, getCellValue(cell).toString());
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pstmt.setString(4, getCellValue(cell).toString());
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        pstmt.setString(5, getCellValue(cell).toString());
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        pstmt.setString(6, getCellValue(cell).toString());
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        pstmt.setString(7, getCellValue(cell).toString());
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        pstmt.setString(8, getCellValue(cell).toString());
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        break;
                }
            }  
            pstmt.addBatch();
            if(i % batchSize == 0)
            {
                pstmt.executeBatch();
            }
        }
        
        //Executing the remaining queries.
        pstmt.executeBatch();
        returnCode = DBConst.DB_SUCCESS;
        conn.commit();
        
        fuf = new FileUploadFactory();
        returnCode = fuf.executeValidation(userID); // This calls the Validation Stored Procedure
        rowCount = Integer.toString(rowNum - 8);
    
        switch (returnCode) {
            case DBConst.DB_SUCCESS:
                bean.setReturnCode(DBConst.DB_SUCCESS);
                bean.setMessage(DataList.getRowStatus()); 
                break;
            case DBConst.DB_FAIL:
                bean.setReturnCode(DBConst.DB_FAIL);
                bean.setMessage("Error storing file");
                break;
            case DBConst.DB_WARNING:
                bean.setReturnCode(DBConst.DB_WARNING);
                bean.setMessage("File stored with warnings"+ rowCount + " rows successfully loaded.");
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        bean.setReturnCode(DBConst.DB_FAIL);
        bean.setMessage("Error storing file");
        Configuration.getInstance().getTelemetry().trackException(e);
    }
}
```

The Validation Stored Procedure call is as follows:

```
public int executeValidation(String userID) {
    int returnCode = -1;
    Connection conn = null;
        
    try {
        conn = SqlDBConnect.getConnection("DATADB");
                    
        String sql = "EXEC [dbo].[Data_ImportValidation] ? ;";
        PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        s.setEscapeProcessing(true);
        s.setQueryTimeout(3600);
        s.setString(1, userID);
        s.execute();
        conn.commit();
        returnCode = DBConst.DB_SUCCESS;         
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        returnCode = DBConst.DB_FAIL;
        Configuration.getInstance().getTelemetry().trackException(e);       
    } finally {
        if(conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Configuration.getInstance().getTelemetry().trackException(e);
            } 
        }
    }
              
    return returnCode;
}
```

Once the validation is complete, we write the validation results into the same excel user uploaded and send it to the user.

I have tried increasing the timeouts on the Stored procedure executions but that did not work. I am still getting timeout issues. I am aware that there is improvement that is needed to done on the Stored Procedure but is there something that can be updated in the code which can help me counter such scenarios. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that if you run procedure in async, you won't be able to display the error to the user since the call will complete.

Comment: If you want to run DB calls async you should probably be using [r2dbc](https://r2dbc.io/).

Comment: btw, i think it's better to use Multi-value construct, performance-wise. like values(?,?,?), (?,?,?). now you still do a lot of inserts. you need to check your web framework for timeouts i guess? or what's the actual timeout error you're getting

Comment: The timeout error I get is Error 500 - Web Server timed out. I am using Java Servlet and JSP pages for the application